# Decoding and Using VITC?

Tags: video, timecode

Can any one give me more explanation on VITC? I need to identify the VITC code presented in the VBI signal. How does it's format work? how does one extract it? How are VITC embedded in a video signal?

I need solution both for Analog Composite video as well as Digital MPEG TS file.